# I'm not understanding the OPENQUERY Function

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, openquery, mdx-query

I need help understanding the OPENQUERY-Structure.

I am trying to understand why the following Query (in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016 (Version 13.0.16106.4)) only produces an error

```
WITH MDXQuery
(
  [AKPIValue]  
)
as
( 
  SELECT     
    convert(decimal(20,2) ,"[KPIValue]") as AKPIValue    
  FROM OPENQUERY(SSAS2,
    'WITH
       MEMBER [KPIValue] AS 10 --(([Measures].[AverageOverTime], [Signal].[Type].[E-Current]))
    SELECT NON EMPTY
    {
      [KPIValue]
    }ON COLUMNS
    ,
    {
      [Time].[Week Calendar].[Day]} * {[Device].[Devices].&[{873AADF4-3D7A-4F25-A6BD-EC1E0A7077C6}]
    } 
    dimension Properties MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_KEY ON ROWS
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT
      {
        [Time].[Month].&[2019-12-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Month].&[2020-03-01T00:00:00]
      } ON COLUMNS     
      from [Measurements]
    )' 
  )
)


SELECT
  MDXQuery.*
From 
  MDXQuery;
```

while another query doesn't

```
with MQ
(
  [LastActivity]
  ,[LurtActivity]
)
as
(
SELECT 
  convert(nvarchar(max),"[Measures].[LastActivity]") as ABC
  ,convert(nvarchar(max),"[Measures].[LurtActivity]") as ABCDE
FROM OPENQUERY(SSAS2,
  'with 
     member [Measures].[LastActivity] as Tail(nonempty([Time].[Minute].[Minute].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Count]),1).Item(0).Name
     member [Measures].[LurtActivity] as 10
   select 
     NON EMPTY 
     {
       [Measures].[LastActivity]
       ,[Measures].[LurtActivity]
     } ON COLUMNS
   from [Measurements]' 
))

Select MQ.* from MQ;
```

When I execute the first one I always get the error Message "Invalid column name '[KPIValue]'" and I don't know why.

I've been trying to understand the structure of the query by playing with the syntax a bit to see if I could discern a pattern, as I was unable to find proper explanations online so far.

For example I don't know why I need to use double quotation marks in the line

```
convert(nvarchar(max),"[Measures].[LastActivity]") as ABC
```

Or why the "as ABC" seems to be irrelevant.

If I execute either of the MDX-Queries in SSRS I get a Resultset back.

Comment: `"[KPIValue]"` is a synonym, for `[[KPIValue]]]`. Your column is simply called `KPIValue` and *if* you delimit identify it, which you don't need to, it would be `[KPIValue]` (using Transact-SQL syntax) or `"KPIValue"` (using ISO SQL syntax). This is just a typographical error; remove the extra delimit identifiers, or even both.

Comment: @Larnu as fas as I know [ and ] is used for when a Name has whitespaces in it or to navigate the dimensions in a cube.

I changed all occurences of [KPIValue] to KPIValue and now get the error

Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 64

Comment: *"Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 64"* Isn't the full error...

Comment: An error occurred while preparing the query "WITH...)" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "SSAS2". 

Is the rest if that helps

Comment: I am executing both queries on the machine that hosts the database, 
logged into Windows as Admin 
using Windows Authentication to Connect to the SQL Server.

The linked server is configured to use the Admin-Account as Security Context for undefined Server Logins

Comment: Why don't you try  `SELECT  *   FROM FROM OPENQUERY(SSAS2,.....` on the first one and see what columns it actually produces

Comment: The first Query doesn't execute in Management Studio; in SSRS I get the values just fine if I just execute the MDX-Query.

Nonetheless, I believe that I'm handling the MDX-Query incorrectly somehow.
Is it correct that I need to map the "Select"-Fields to the Fields of the MDX-Resultset?
And is it correct, that this is done with the value between the ".."?

Comment: @Larnu, I managed to get my query to work when I added "[Measures]." in front of my Fields.

So it looks like this now:

SELECT 
  convert(nvarchar(max),"[Measures].[KPIValue]",120) as ABC
...
MEMBER [Measures].[KPIValue] AS 10 


I have no idea why [Measures] is so integral to the query though.
Could someone clear this up for me?